# Will Acronis True Image WD Edition work on the Western Digital-owned HGST drives?

Tags: hard-drive, acronis-trueimage

We have a copy of Acronis True Image WD Edition and we'd like to know whether or not it will work on HGST (owned by Western Digital) drives?

Comment: When you go to "About" or whatever the button interface says.  What is the name of the exact program?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. The software isn't installed yet. Are there hard and fast rules to go by

Comment: If you can't tell me then I cannot answer this question.  That information would indicate if you can or can't use the software with other HDDs

Comment: Is it a case that the latest versions work?

Comment: How about this.  Install the software.  It will likely work.  You don't indicate what version you have so I have no idea if the "lastest" version will work.

Comment: Acronis True Image WD Edition, Build: 5962

Answer (score 0):

### No.

The WD branded Acronis [found at the WD website](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=119) does not work for Hitachi branded drives.

[image]

However, the same installer does in fact work for WD branded portable HDDs, and it does not require that the file be copied to or from the WD branded drive.