# How do I install Western Digital Acronis True Image?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, acronis-trueimage

I can't install Acronis True Image from

https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en#WD_softwarepc

It gives me this error.

[image]

But I have *THREE* Western Digital drives installed!

[image]

I want to clone my failing OS disk to a new drive so I don't have to re-install an OS.

Windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you attempted to contact Acronis or Western Digital about this problem?  It's possible the offer simply has expired

Comment: [However, the same installer does in fact work for WD branded portable HDDs, and it does not require that the file be copied to or from the WD branded drive.](https://superuser.com/questions/838157/will-acronis-true-image-wd-edition-work-on-the-western-digital-owned-hgst-drives) You should try that

Comment: @Ramhound What do you want me to try? I cannot continue past the splash screen! I do not have a Hitachi drive! Yes, I have contacted Western Digital. There is no 'offer'. The download is a static download on their support page that's been through years of updates according to the release notes.

Comment: Thought it was obvious “However, the same installer does in fact work for WD branded portable HDDs, and it does not require that the file be copied to or from the WD branded drive.”, and the offer is a free version of Acronis but free versions bundled with products expire

Comment: @Chloe I removed the `western-digital` tag on your question. [We don't use company or manufacturer tags](https://meta.superuser.com/a/8403/213131).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acronis is well-known for lagging behind on support for newer disk models.
It also has the gotcha that its backup uses Windows, so works with any disk,
while its recovery boot media uses its own drivers which may not support
the hardware (this catastrophe happened to me).

I would suggest using instead other free products that do not have
these restrictions. Some of them are (in no particular order):

- [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)
- [Macrium Reflect Free Edition](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)
- [EaseUS Todo Backup Free](https://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm)
- [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)
- [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)
- [AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html)
  (no cloning in free version, but very flexible backup+restore)

Comment: I found Clonezilla via https://alternativeto.net/software/acronis-true-image/ and I used that. It was very complicated to setup and install, but it appeared to work. After the first pass, I saw bad sectors, so had to drop to command line and re-run their command with `--rescue` option so it wouldn't stop on a bad sector. My Dell was a nightmare because apparently it locks up and the BIOS doesn't even start if you switch component cables. You have to fully unplug it for 5m each time!

Comment: The Clonezilla user interface is quite old. Other products like MiniTool, EaseUS and Macrium use a more modern interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's the firmware of the HDD's in need of update as the revisions of Acronis imaging software are updated, it will not support or even be able to identify older firmware on older HDD's.

You will have to update the firmware of your HDD's first. **the link to firmware update is on the website you provided** This will change the device ID's to be readable/accepted by Acronis current revision.

There are several workarounds to this but I suggest flashing the firmware via Manufacturer site support to the latest rev. is a good practice for security purposes. If your HDD's are at end of support life, that would be the only reason to use any older rev. of Acronis.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't make sense. You are saying that the HDs are too old, and Acronis is too new. However, the latest release of Acronis is 12/16/2016 and 2/3 of the hard drives are brand new. One has a manufactured date 9/19/2017. That logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Chloe: Right. Your disks are probably newer than that firmware, and installing bad firmware can brick any device *and* void your warranty. Acronis is not worth that risk and I believe you should forget it. I deleted my answer because of peer pressure, but will undelete it if you ask.

Comment: @harrymc I would undelete it in case someone needs to clone a non-system disk.